# express next throwing error as next is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to pass some predefined functions in the callback of `app.post()` method. I am getting next is not defined error. Below is my code. Please suggest where I am doing wrong or am I missing any concept here?

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express()

app.post('/api/signup', function(req, res) {
validateParams(req, res, next),
dbCall(req, res, next),
sendResponse(req, res)
})
```

where I have each function defined and imported and returning next() after my process.

my validateParams function is below :

```
validateParams = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("at validator ", req);
    next();
}

module.exports = validateParams;
```

my dbCall function is below :

```
dbCall = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("at dbCall ", req);
    next();
}

module.exports = dbCall;
```

my sendResponse function is below :

```
sendResponse = function(req, res) {
    console.log("at dbCall ", res);
    res.send("Response sent successfully");
}

module.exports = sendResponse;
```

Comment: can you share other functions (validateParams,dbCall) as well?

Comment: I think you want to work them as a middle-ware function, in this case, you can reference these functions right after the path in your `app.post()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to use `validateParams(req, res, next)` and `dbCall(req, res, next)` as middleware functions. In this case, you need something like this:

```
const validateParams = (req, res, next) => {
  // do stuff here
  next();
}

const dbCall = (req, res, next) => {
  // do stuff here
  next();
}

app.post('/api/signup', validateParams, dbCall, function(req, res) {

sendResponse(req, res)
})
```

You can read more [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples)

Comment: You don't need to wrap `sendResponse`, or add `next ` to your wrapper

Comment: @ponury-kostek `sendResponse()` is being used by OP in his code, I just copied it. You are right, we don't need to wrap `res.send()`, not for this use case at least. And, what do you mean by "add `next` to your wrapper"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ponury-kostek I think you are talking about something like the following:

`const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const fun1 = (req, res) => {
 console.log("fun1");
}

const fun2 = (req, res) => {
 console.log("fun2");
}

app.get("/unit", (req, res, next) => {
 fun1(req, res, next);
 fun2(req, res, next);
 res.send("ok");
});`

app.listen(3000);`

Comment: @ponury-kostek But the follwoing does not work:

`const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const fun1 = (req, res) => {
 console.log('fun1');
}

const fun2 = (req, res) => {
 console.log('fun2');
}

app.get('/unit', fun1, fun2, (req, res, next) => {
 res.send('ok');
});

app.listen(3000);`

Comment: I'm talking about this: `app.post('/api/signup', validateParams, dbCall, sendResponse);`, this is simplest working solution.

Answer (score 10):

You probably forgot to add the `next` argument in your callback.

```
app.post('/api/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  validateParams(req, res, next),
  dbCall(req, res, next),
  sendResponse(req, res)
})
```

Comment: this doesnt work. this struck at first function and never executes second. and am just consoling in all the function.