# NODE JS -- Get Snowflake Query results from a function results in udefined

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been trying to run a simple query through Node JS and snowflake.
the results are showing when I log it to the console but when trying to call the query from other function I can't use the results (undefined variable):

```
  async function getSnowData(){
   const snow_data = await connection.execute({
     sqlText: 'SELECT * from snow_tbl;',
     complete:function(err,stmt,rows){
       return(rows);
     }
   });
return snow_data;
}



app.get("/snowdata", async (req, res) => {
 try {
   const snow_data= await getSnowData();
   console.log(snow_data);

 } catch (error) {
   console.error('Error in main process:', error.message);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getSnowData` function does not return a value. It should probably return `snow_data`

```js
async function getSnowData(){
   const snow_data = await connection.execute({
     sqlText: 'SELECT * from snow_tbl;',
     complete:function(err, stmt, rows){
       return(rows);
     }
   });

   return snow_data;
}
```

Comment: added it, still not working..

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Node and was having the same issue. After a bunch of logging and Googling, here's what I came up with.

- The key is to put the data in the response locals variable scope and use the next() statement to proceed to the next layer in the middleware. The next layer in the middleware will have access to the res.locals variables.

ie
`res.locals.rows = rows` assigns the returned rows to the response,

`next()` in getSnowData(),

goes back the function it was called from and executes the callback function

and

```
const snow_data = getSnowData(req, res, function() {...
```

This anonymous function in the third parameter of getSnowData is only executed after next() is called inside getSnowData.

I tested your example successfully, and also added a JSON response back containing the rows. I also removed the async portion.

```
function getSnowData(req, res, next){
    const snow_data = connection.execute({
      sqlText: 'SELECT * from snow_tbl;',
      complete:function(err,stmt,rows){
        console.log(rows.length)
        res.locals.rows = rows
        next()
      }
    });
 }

app.get("/snowdata", (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const snow_data = getSnowData(req, res, function(rows) {
        console.log(res.locals.rows);
        res.json({response: res.locals.rows})
      });
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in main process:', error.message);
    }
   });
```

I found these links helpful:

- [How to make a function wait until a callback has been called using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js)
- [express next throwing error as next is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675587/express-next-throwing-error-as-next-is-not-defined)